# Use method to iterate over child components in a modal in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

So I have a modal that has a dynamic number of table rows in a table.  The user is able to update the table rows (they can edit some info).  I want to be able to then click the save button to call a method that iterates through each row and saves that new info to the data base. The code for the modal is below...is there any way to iterate over each item to save the updated info?

```
updateCharities () {
}

render() {
return (
  <Modal className="charityModal" show={this.props.show} onHide={this.props.onHide}>
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
      <Modal.Title>Update Your Charity Selections</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>

    <Modal.Body>
      <Table>
        <thead>
          <tr> 
            <th>Charity Name</th>
            <th>Total Donations</th>
            <th>Current Percentage Donation</th>
            <th>Remove Charity</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          {this.state.charities.map((charity, i) => 
            // {console.log('charity', charity.percentage)}
            <CharityModalEntry key={i} charity={charity} />
          )}
        </tbody>
      </Table>

    </Modal.Body>

    <Modal.Footer>
      <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.updateCharities}>Save</Button>
      <Button>Cancel</Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
  </Modal>
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the state of this.state.charities consistent with what is entered into each of the table rows, then when you come to update you don't need to do any iteration as you have the relevant data available in the parent state.  You can do this by passing a callback function into each CharityModalEntry that updates the parent's state.

For example, in parent:

```
rowUpdated(i, newCharityData) {
    const charitiesSlice= this.state.charities.slice();
    charitiesSlice[i] = newCharityData;
    this.setState({
       charities: charitiesSlice
    });
}
```

Also in parent, when you render CharityModalEntry:

```
<tbody>
    {this.state.charities.map((charity, i) => 
        <CharityModalEntry 
          key={i} 
          charity={charity} 
          onUpdate={newData => rowUpdated(i, newData)} 
        />
    )}
</tbody>
```

Then in the CharityModalEntry component (using charityName as an example):

```
constructor() {
    this.state = {
        charity: this.props.charity
    }
    //NB: You may want to implement componentWillReceiveProps() as well.
}

updateName(event) {
    const charitySlice = this.state.charity.slice();
    charitySlice.name = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
        charity: charitySlice
    });
    this.props.onUpdate(this.state.charity);
}

render() {
    return (
        <input 
          id="charityName" 
          onBlur={e => this.updateName(e)} 
          value={this.state.charity.name} 
        />
    );
}
```